# CSS is not hiding overflow - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I have an issue with quantity element in checkout that its overlapping the number value making hard for customer to add multiple products. If I use **{display:none}**  css value it hides not only text overlapping but "QUANTITY" text as well. Its only on detail page where user needs to add quantity of product. I couldn't find a way to fix this. [This](https://www.jetronics.ae/product/hc625-mini-drone-6-axis-rc-micro-quadcopters/) is the url and help is much appreciated. [image] is also attached.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can use Inspect element to see CSS values. Its WordPress/WooCommerce.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat Please post the code. I should not have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat Sorry, I didn't see your link but it would be more helpful if you just posted the relevant code here so we don't need to go off site and search through your website to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which selector you use `display: block` but it should work:

```
.quantity .screen-reader-text {
    display: none
}
```

I would suggest implementation of the `.screen-reader-text` css class as [documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/accessibility/handbook/best-practices/markup/the-css-class-screen-reader-text/) to preserve accesibility:

```
/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

Seems like your theme is missing the css definition which should fix your problem without enforcing `display: block`.

Comment: @Martin thanks a bundle your first piece of code worked without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your custom CSS:

```
form.cart td.value label.screen-reader-text{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

or:

```
form.cart td.value label.screen-reader-text{
        display: none!important;
}
```